# Check seleted radio with value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to count all selected radio to a certain value?

I have done this:

```
if($('.giornal:checked').val() == 'option1'.length == 1) {

 // something

}
```

Comment: Still not clear! Explain more!

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please add `HTML` code and please try to explain what you're trying to achieve and where do you have problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all radio buttons checked as you shared in your question then filter array matching specific value(here "1") and get length

```js
var res = $("input[type=radio]:checked").filter(function(){
  return "1"==$(this).val()
})

console.log(res.length)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" checked value="1"/>
<input type="radio" checked value="1"/>
<input type="radio" checked value="3"/>
<input type="radio" value="4"/>
```